Nodejs opentelemetry redis context propagation on publish subscribe
I'm new to opentelemetry.
I would like to know if it is possible to automatically propagate context to subscribers when publishing a notification on Redis.
I would like to see children subscribers spans under publisher span all inside the same trace
I found an article describing how to manually achieve this, but is this the only way? Is it possible to automatically propagate context?
For instance installing @opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node and setting OTEL_PROPAGATORS properly.
Thank you.
